# Optimize neo4j cypher import query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization, driver

I created an application in C# using Neo4j.Driver.V1 that reads from a CSV and writes it into a neo4j graph database.

My csv has 1000 records. Each record is split into 5 nodes with relationships between them.

The whole process is taking 1 min 11 seconds (including 1 second for my logic behind to build the query).

This is way too much considering they will be uploading millions of records.

Here is my query:

```
MERGE 
    (accountd71d278a8eeb468f9e4517ac1e007fe5:Account 
        { 
            number: '952'
        } )         
ON CREATE 
    SET accountd71d278a8eeb468f9e4517ac1e007fe5 += 
    { 
        number: '952', 
        balanceType: 2, 
        accountType: 2, 
        openDate: apoc.date.parse('7/9/2015', 'ms', 'm/d/YYYY')
    }

MERGE (account13aa03cd1b6d449e88a3e5e5a22353da:Account 
    { 
        number: '198'
    } ) 
ON CREATE 
    SET account13aa03cd1b6d449e88a3e5e5a22353da += 
    { 
        number: '198'
    } 

MERGE (transactionba1459c4f7854157be237e7365497fcf:Transaction 
    { 
        number: '1'
    } ) 

ON CREATE 
    SET transactionba1459c4f7854157be237e7365497fcf += 
    { 
        number: '1', 
        amount: 3717.81, 
        type: 2, 
        date: apoc.date.parse('2016-05-27', 'ms', 'YYYY-mm-dd')
    }  

MERGE (bank3679799504f54bed9f079848be9c6eff:Bank 
    { 
        code: 'MMBC'
    } ) 
ON CREATE 
    SET bank3679799504f54bed9f079848be9c6eff += 
    { 
        code: 'MMBC', 
        country: 'Mongolia'
    }  

MERGE (bank522b6b6ed04d40bd9d87d4ecc36fbde2:Bank 
    { 
        code: 'VALL'
    } ) 
ON CREATE 
    SET bank522b6b6ed04d40bd9d87d4ecc36fbde2 += 
    { 
        code: 'VALL', 
        country: 'Mongolia'
    }  

MERGE (accountd71d278a8eeb468f9e4517ac1e007fe5)-[:credits]->(transactionba1459c4f7854157be237e7365497fcf) 
MERGE (accountd71d278a8eeb468f9e4517ac1e007fe5)-[:residesWith]->(bank3679799504f54bed9f079848be9c6eff) 
MERGE (transactionba1459c4f7854157be237e7365497fcf)-[:debits]->(account13aa03cd1b6d449e88a3e5e5a22353da) 
MERGE (account13aa03cd1b6d449e88a3e5e5a22353da)-[:residesWith]->(bank522b6b6ed04d40bd9d87d4ecc36fbde2)
```

Any ideas how I can reduce the time of my query?

Before offering any ideas, here is what I tried already:

1. Removing the long names with GUID
2. Remove use of apoc date parse
3. Considered using the import from csv in-build functionality but the db is on another server
4. Combined multiple record queries (and resulted that 2 at once performs best)
5. Created constraints

Thanks in advance!

K

[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: For every `MERGE`  you should have an index (or a better a unique constraint) on the label+property you are using for it

Comment: Can give us the `EXPLAIN` of the query ?

Comment: Hey thanks logisma.. As I said, it has constraints already.. not sure what you mean by EXPLAIN of the query.. sorry new to cypher here

Comment: @logisima added the EXPLAIN.. i think :)

Comment: You are not using the `LOAD CSV` feature right ? How do you handle transactions in your code ? Can share a little bit of your code ? Your query is not parametrized, is it normal ?

Comment: @logisima No I cannot use Load CSV since this is on another server. Parameters are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is list of point to optimize your process :

- Use **query parameters** : All your query data should be a parameter. If you do it, Neo4j will not recompute every time the query planner
- **Batch your queries** : I think you do one transaction for each row of your CSV. Try to bacth your queries (one transaction for 1000 row should be OK, but if your CSV will grow, you will really need more transactions)
- Create **one query per node/relationship creation** instead of doing one big query, and for the relation use the `MATCH MATCH MERGE` pattern (you have the constraint, so it will be fast)